# Hibernate validator error Spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm getting:

> javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000032: Unable to initialize
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.PatternValidator

My `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

No other error is showing, even with debug-mode logging.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9.- ]*"); here is the code
```

Comment: Did you - by any chance - actually used a Validator somewhere?

Comment: @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9.- ]*"); here is the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The error you are getting is due to your regexp being invalid.** To solve it you need change your regexp to something really basic:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]*");
```

Then gradually add the extra characters to spot what is causing the error. It could be two dashes or the space, but you can easily test it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your regexp here is with dash used inside of it. Put dash at the beginning:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[-0-9. ]*");
```